# Setting up of session in Laravel API

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I trying to set session in API.For that purpose added these code inside api middleware (Kernel.php)

```
   \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
    \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
```

when runing the application , everything fine except setting up of session

```
if($result)
{
             session()->put('UID',$result->UserID);
            session()->put('BID',$result->rBranchID);
}
else     {
            $Status='Failed';
        }
```

while try to display one  session, it showing null. I want to put session on these variables.

I dont know what things should add at the top of the controller. I added below things.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers;
```

Comment: what is your use-case? this sounds a bit off

Comment: I want  login to a laravel application from out side. Am looking for is it possible or not.

Comment: @TestCheck: Yes it possible with Token based authentication along with CORS allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel api is stateless means session will not work in api middleware.

If you really want session then you can move your routes from `api.php` to `web.php` with `api` prefix and then you can use session there.

Comment: could you please explain .. right now am using this code inside api.php  
  Route::group(['middleware' => ['sessions']], function () {
   Route::post('/login','ApiController@index');

});

Comment: I think you should not use session for authentication , use token base authentication